# Powershell - Batch Rename Multiple Files with Padding Zeros

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to use PowerShell to batch rename multiple images within the same folder.

It's on a work computer so I can't install any external programs and I can only point PowerShell to the folder if I use the shift + right click function within the folder (The command that says "Open PowerShell window here")(There's a bunch of strict admin rules on that work computer).

I've been trying to use this command:

```
dir *.jpg | ForEach-Object -begin { $count=1 } -process { rename-item $_ -NewName "cat000$count.jpg"; $count++ }
```

However, it is not exactly what I'm looking for.

I'm looking to batch rename multiple files so they look like the following:

```
Cat0001 Cat0002 Cat0010
```

So the command should identify when it flips over to the 10s and only adds two zeros instead of three.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use [`-f` format operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51912544/3439404) (description [How-to: The `-f` Format operator](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-f-operator.html)):

```
$fileExtension='jpg'
Get-ChildItem -Filter "*.$fileExtension" |
    Where-Object { -not ($_.BaseName  -match "^cat\d{4}$") } |
    ForEach-Object -Begin { $count=1 } -Process {
        $newName = "cat{0:d4}.$fileExtension" -f $count
        $count++
        #  optional: what-if the $newName file already exists?
        While (Test-Path -Path $newName) {
            $newName = "cat{0:d4}.$fileExtension" -f $count
            $count++
        }
        Write-Host Rename-Item -NewName $newName -Path $_.FullName
     }
```

Here

- `Where-Object {…}` excludes already renamed files from processing (note that the `"^cat\d{4}$"` regex could not suffice if there are more than 9999 files,
- `While (Test-Path -Path $newName) {…}` loop prevents unwanted overwriting files (exception *Rename-Item : Cannot create a file when that file already exists.*), and
- `Write-Host …` is used merely for debugging purposes (I dislike the `-WhatIf` parameter for its verbosity).